# .htaccess RewriteRule with the same link name

Tags: .htaccess

The following code is my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^story$ story.html [L]
RewriteRule ^story/([0-9]+)/$ story2.html?seq=$1 [L]
```

As you can see, my intention is quite simple.
I want to change links like story.html to story and story2.html?seq=$1 to story/(variable number)

The former works well BUT story2.html?seq=$1 doesn't work. I think it's because I use the same name "story" in the link. How can I solve this problem without changing it to another name?

Answer (score 0):

On the second rule, because you are rewriting to a URL containing query arguments, you need to let the rewrite engine know that like so:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([0-9]+)/$ story2.html?seq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` means "Query String Append" and let's mod_rewrite know that you are appending query parameters.

- [Apache mod_rewrite documentation for RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. but I still have the same problem. When I type /story/40/ or whatever after /story/40/, it shows http://URL/story.

Comment: But if I use the different name to ^topic/([0-9]+)/$ story2.html?seq=$1, it works fine.